# How to type monospaced numbers using system font in macOS?

Tags: font

The San Francisco font uses proportionally spaced numbers by default, however it does support monospaced ones. As a developer I know how to make it use monospaced numbers when showing text in an app, but I have no idea how to type them while using text editors such as Notes.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I'm currently using Helvetica Neue for monospaced numbers as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this would be Format > Font > Show Fonts, click on the gear wheel at top left, then on Typography, then select the right variation for numbers.

Comment: Can you confirn that this approach works in Notes? When I tried this, the little window said “multiple fonts selected” or smth like that.

Comment: @NikitaKukushkin  No, it appears to be broken at this time.  Presumably a bug to report to Apple for fixing in a future update.

Comment: @NikitaKukushkin I think Notes may be too primitive for this kind of thing.